# Why is Brave browser launching automatically on startup on macOS Ventura even thought it is not in start up items?

Tags: macos, brave

Brave Browser launches itself automatically when I start my computer up.

Previously I could go into my user account and remove it from login items, but macOS Ventura changed the entire System Preferences screen. Brave no longer appears here, and yet still launches automatically:

[image: Login Items on MacOS Ventura]

Right-clicking on brave in the dock and selecting "Options" also shows that "open at login" is not checked:

[image: Context menu]

What gives? Why is it still opening at login, and how do I stop it?

Comment: Does it still launch even if you quit it before shutdown? [Always give it a couple of minutes after quit before shutdown, as the list can take a minute to populate].

Comment: Did you just update to macOS Ventura? If so I would recommend downloading [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) and clear out old caches. Download, it launch it, go to the “Maintenance” tab, and then click “Run Tasks” and your system will restart and hopefully Brave won’t launch anymore. The idea is that somehow some cached setting is causing this to happen and Onyx purging caches would clear this up. Onyx is pretty safe so doing this won’t hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

Open Apple, click, System Settings, go to General, click Login Items, at top click “Brave” to highlight it, Click -. Restart Mac (Ventura).

Success, It's gone.

Now I can start Brave to order.

Answer (score 0):

From a Windows answer:  [Check your extensions loaded in Brave](https://community.brave.com/t/a-website-opens-everytime-i-launch-brave/398163).  Specifically any extension that needs to interact outside of the browser.  Thus, it would need to be loaded to work with other parts of the OS.   In my case, it was [Mailto: Set Default Email to Gmail by cloudHQ](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/mailto-set-default-email/boljkhffeonkhcipdflndnljbhigbhhe)

[image]

After disabling this extension, the Brave Browser startup was removed from the Task Manager Startup tab.   But the Brave VPN loader was still there (disabled :)